# Comment all lines from last commented line to line with 'foo'

Tags: text-processing, sed

Consider a text file `users.txt`:

```
#alice
#bob
charlie
dotan
eric
```

I need to comment everything from (exclusive) the last commented line until (inclusive) `dotan`. This is the result:

```
#alice
#bob
#charlie
#dotan
eric
```

**Is there a nice `sed` oneliner to do this?** I'll be happy with any tool, not just `sed`, really.

Currently I am getting the line number of the last commented line as so:

```
$ cat -n users.txt | grep '#' | tail -n1
  2 #bob
```

I then add one and comment with `sed`:

```
$ sed -i'' '3,/dotan/ s/^/#/' users.txt
```

I know that I could be clever and put this all together with some `bc` into an ugly one-liner. **Surely there must be a cleaner way?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
perl -pe '$n=1 if s/^dotan/#$&/; s/^[^#]/#$&/ unless $n==1;' file
```

or, the same idea in awk:

```
awk '(/^dotan/){a=1; sub(/^/,"#",$1)} (a!=1 && $1!~/^#/){sub(/^/,"#",$1);}1; ' file
```

Answer (score 7):

If the existing commented lines form a single contiguous block, then you could match from the *first* commented line instead, commenting-out only those lines up to and including your end pattern that are not already commented

```
sed '/^#/,/dotan/ s/^[^#]/#&/' file
```

If the existing comments are not contiguous, then due to the greedy nature of the sed range match I think you would need to do something like

```
tac file | sed '/dotan/,/^#/ s/^[^#]/#&/' | tac
```

i.e. match *upwards* from the end pattern to the 'first' comment - obviously that's not so convenient if you want an in-place solution though.

Answer (score 4):

You can handle both cases (commented lines in a single contiguous block or interspersed among uncommented lines) with a single `sed` invocation:

```
sed '1,/PATTERN/{/^#/{x;1d;b};//!{H;/PATTERN/!{1h;d};//{x;s/\n/&#/g}}}' infile
```

This processes only the lines in the `1,/PATTERN/` range. It e`x`changes hold space w. pattern space every time a line is commented (so there is never more than one commented line in the hold buffer)  and appends every line that is not commented to the `H`old space (when on 1st line, `1d` and respectively `1h` are also needed to remove the initial empty line in the hold buffer).
When it reaches the line matching PATTERN, it also appends it to the `H`old buffer, e`x`changes the buffers and then replaces every `\n`ewline character in the pattern space with a `\n`ewline and a `#` (that is, all lines in pattern space will now begin with `#`, including the first line as the first line in the hold space is always a commented line).
With a sample `infile`:

```
alice
#bob
bill
#charlie
ding
dong
dotan
jimmy
#garry
```

running:

```
sed '1,/dotan/{                   # if line is in this range    -start c1
/^#/{                             # if line is commented        -start c2
x                                 # exchage hold space w. pattern space
1d                                # if 1st line, delete pattern space
b                                 # branch to end of script
}                                 #                             -end c2
//!{                              # if line is not commented    -start c3
H                                 # append to hold space
/dotan/!{                         # if line doesn't match dotan -start c4
1h                                # if 1st line, overwrite hold space
d                                 # delete pattern space
}                                 #                             -end c4
//{                               # if line matches dotan       -start c5
x                                 # exchage hold space w. pattern space
s/\n/&#/g                         # add # after each newline character
}                                 #                             -end c5
}                                 #                             -end c3
}' infile                         #                             -end c1
```

outputs:

```
alice
#bob
bill
#charlie
#ding
#dong
#dotan
jimmy
#garry
```

so it's commenting only lines from (and excluding) `#charlie` up to (and including) `dotan` and leaving the other lines untouched.
Sure, this assumes there's always at least one commented line before the line matching `PATTERN`. If that's not the case you could add an additional check before the replacement: `/^#/{s/\n/&#/g}`

Comment: Thank you, I will have quite a bit to learn from this answer!

Comment: Hang on, I must have screwed up. This isn't about the *last* series of commented lines? No, I get it, it is. The last series + dotan. Pretty damn clever.

Comment: You always find the best questions. Damned dotan had me thrown for awhile - maybe still does, i havent tested it yet. thanks, don.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `sed`:

```sh
sed  -e:n -e'/\n#.*\ndotan/!{$!{N;/^#/bn'      \
-eb  -e\} -e'/^#/s/\(\n\)\(dotan.*\)*/\1#\2/g' \
-et  -e\} -eP\;D <in >out
```

That does as you ask. It just works on a stack - building it when necessary and for as long as necessary between occurences of commented lines, and dumping the old buffer in favor of the new commented line further on in input when it finds one. Picture...

[image]

Sorry, I don't know why I did that. But it came to mind.

Anyway, `sed` spreads its buffers between each last commented line in any series, never retaining a single more in its buffer than is necessary to accurately track the last commented occurrence, and if at any time it encounters the last line while doing so it will attempt the final `g`lobal execution statement and branch `t`est the whole buffer out to be printed, else it will `P`rint all of those lines it releases from its buffer as soon as it does.

I guess this is what brought the accordions to mind...

```sh
printf %s\\n   \#alice \#bob charlie dotan eric \
               \#alice \#bob charlie dotan eric \
               \#alice \#bob charlie dotan eric |
sed  -e:n -e'l;/\n#.*\ndotan/!{$!{N;/^#/bn'     \
-eb  -e\} -e'/^#/s/\(\n\)\(dotan.*\)*/\1#\2/g'  \
-et  -e\} -eP\;D
```

---

```
#alice
#alice\n#bob$
#alice\n#bob\ncharlie$
#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#alice
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#bob
charlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
charlie
dotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
dotan
eric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
eric
#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#alice
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#bob
charlie\ndotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
charlie
dotan\neric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
dotan
eric\n#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
eric
#alice\n#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#alice
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan$
#bob\ncharlie\ndotan\neric$
#bob
#charlie
#dotan
eric
```

There's only one difference between this command and the one above and that is the `l`ook command at the top. When we `l`ook at `sed`'s pattern space as it works we can get a better idea of what goes on behind the scenes and a better understanding of how to direct its efforts.

In this case we can watch `sed` stack input until has found a second occurrence of `\n#.*\ndotan` in input, and that when it starts printing the previous out a line at a time. It's kinda cool. I learned a lot working on this.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! The final paragraph with explanations is terrific, I will spend quite some time learning from this post as well. Nice stack!

Comment: @dotancohen - this was a really good question. Have a look at the edit to see the *stack*.

Comment: I notice in the edit history the entry `Handle many dotans`. I'm sure that this is my wife's worst nightmare.

Comment: @dotancohen - yeah, this was a tough one. Stuff like `#\ndotan\ndotan` is hard for these things. I mean it when I say this a good question. I *think* I got it just about perfect, but one problem you *could* run into is if your comment blocks are separated by a 1000 lines - that *will* slow it down. You might stick something like `s/\n/&/150;t` in before the first `/\n#` thing to break out the buffer if it spans 150 lines, for example. And anyway, maybe it's just what she's been waiting for *all along*!